# Consider the map defined by $T:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^2$ defined by $T(x_1 -2x_2 + x_3, 2x_1-3x_2 + x_3)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm asked to find $N(T), R(T)$, a basis for them, and to determine whether it is onto or 1:1. I wrote my mapping in matrix form and I get 
$$\begin{matrix} 
1 & -2 & 1 \\ 2 & -3 & 1 \\ 
\end{matrix}
$$.
After row reducing I obtain:
$$\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{matrix}
$$.
From this I conclude that my third column is dependent hence $N(T) = 1$, not 1:1 but I am clueless about how to obtain a basis for it. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\pmatrix{1&-2&1\\2&-3&1}\to\pmatrix{1&-2&1\\0&1&-1}\to \pmatrix{1&0&-1\\0&1&-1}$ there is one free variable, third column variable, $w.$ set that equal to $1$ and solving for the pivot variables, you find $x = 1, y = 1.$  therefore the null space of $T$ is spanned by $(1,1,1)^T.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Observe $$v=(a,a,a)\quad\implies\quad Tv = 0$$